# Alter path of another server image on my website. Is it possible?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, cross-domain

I have my website which has image stored like following pattern.

```
http://www.site1.com/upload/photos/image1.jpg
http://www.site1.com/upload/photos/image2.png
```

Now i have another website in which i want to use this 2 images but i want that this 2 images path should look like following

```
http://www.site2.com/upload/image1.jpg
http://www.site2.com/upload/image2.png
```

so if i write < img src="http://www.site2.com/upload/image1.jpg" /> it should open image at http://www.site1.com/upload/photos/image1.jpg.

Is it possible on my shared hosting with .HTACESS file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `site2.com` server place this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^upload/(.+)$ http://www.site1.com/upload/photos/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: your solution seems to work 50%. It rewrites properly but not displaying image.In browser it gives error like **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html**. Any solution for that with .htaccess ?

Comment: I have added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in htaccess and it worked. Thank you very much for solution.